# How to pass a string with special chars in python to os.system. (E.g. python test.py |& tee output.txt)

Tags: python, shell, sh

The command will fail as a result of char "&".
E.g. python test.py |& tee output.txt

Answer (score 0):

On my system, using `|&` gives me this error message

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

`|&` is not a syntax supported by `sh`, but it is supported by `bash`. This isn't an issue with "special characters", but rather an issue with the syntax supported by the shell that `os.system()` runs. If this is the error you're getting, you could use this `sh`-compatible syntax instead

```py
os.system("python test.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt")
```